# LogicApp - The template language function 'contains' expects its first argument 'collection' to be a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I have created an Azure Logic App with the Azure Service Bus Queue Trigger (When a message is received in a queue (auto-complete)) for re-processing dead letter queue messages.

In the same Logic App, I’m validating the dead letter message with **DeadLetterReason** and **DeadLetterErrorDescription** properties values and then posting message to active queue.
But for the few dead letter messages doesn’t contains the **DeadLetterErrorDescription** property name and value.

Validation code in the logic app:

```
 "expression": {
                "or": [
                    {
                        "equals": [
                            "@triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DeadLetterReason']",
                            "TTLExpiredException"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "and": [
                            {
                                "not": {
                                    "equals": [
                                        "@triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DeadLetterReason']",
                                        200
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "not": {
                                    "contains": [
                                        "@triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DeadLetterErrorDescription']",
                                        "NotFoundException"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Error:

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Validate_the_DLQ_message_reason_and_description' at line '1' and column '3467': 'The template language function 'contains' expects its first argument 'collection' to be a dictionary (object), an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'.'.

Validation logic:

1. Need to be verify the **DeadLetterReason** and **DeadLetterErrorDescription** properties from Service Bus queue trigger properties.
2. If the above properties exists, then I need to validate the values of those properties.

So, please suggest me how to verify the above property name exists in the received dead letter message or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#coalesce) function to replace `null` with an empty string:

```
"expression": {
    "or": [
        {
            "equals": [
                "@coalesce(triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DeadLetterReason'], '')",
                "TTLExpiredException"
            ]
        },
        {
            "and": [
                {
                    "not": {
                        "equals": [
                            "@coalesce(triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DeadLetterReason'], '')",
                            "200"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "not": {
                        "contains": [
                            "@coalesce(triggerBody()?['Properties']?['DeadLetterErrorDescription'], '')",
                            "NotFoundException"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Please look at the validation logic section in the above updated answer.

Comment: @Pradeep, `coalesce` can be used for the DeadLetterReason in the same manner - updated the answer.